# Django: Filtering the Questions

Tags: python, django

Here's the model,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    ....

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I filter out those questions which received an answer in last 24 hours. How it can I filter them out?

Please help me. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from django.utils import timezone
yesterday = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(hours=24)
recent = Question.objects.filter(answer__timestamp__gte=yesterday).distinct()  # distinct might be necessary
```

The `answer` in the filter kwarg is -- in this order (if provided) -- either the `related_query_name`, the `related_name` or the lower case model name.

Comment: Sir, is there any way so that I order these questions as per the number of answers given in last 24 hours?